# Is there a bash command that can tell the size of a shell variable

Tags: linux, bash

Is there a way to find the size(memory used) of shell variable from command line, without using C ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`wc` can tell you how many characters and bytes are in a variable, and bash itself can tell you how many elements are in an array. If what you're looking for is how large bash's internal structures are for holding a specific variable then I don't believe that's available anywhere.

```
$ foo=42
$ bar=(1 2 3 4)
$ echo -n "$foo" | wc -c -m
      2       2
$ echo "${#bar[@]}"
4
```

Comment: you can just write ${#foo} to get length of string -- check my answer

Comment: @Foo: In characters, yes. Not in bytes.

Comment: If you're really looking for the memory used, you need to add the length of the name and add some overhead. And roughly double for exported variables.

Answer (score 20):

This tells you how many characters are in the value of a scalar variable named "var":

```
echo ${#var}
```

This tells you the number of elements in an array named "array":

```
echo ${#array[@]}
```

This tells you the number of characters in an element of an array:

```
echo ${#array[3]}
```

If you try to get the size of an array and you leave out the `[@]` index, you get the length of element 0:

```
$ array=(1 22 333 4444)
$ echo ${#array}
1
$ echo ${#array[@]}
4
$ echo ${#array[2]}
3
```

If you want the total length of all elements of an array, you could iterate over the array and add them up, you could use `IFS` and some steps similar to those below, or you could:

```
$ tmp="${array[*]}"
$ echo $(( ${#tmp} - ${#array[@]} + 1 ))
10
```

Beware of using the number of elements in an array as the index of the last element since Bash supports sparse arrays:

```
$ array=(1 22 333 4444 55555)
$ echo ${#array[@]}
5
$ array[9]=999999999
$ echo ${#array[@]}
6
$ echo ${array[${#array[@]} - 1]}    # same as echo ${array[6 - 1]}

$ # only a newline is echoed since element 5 is empty (only if "nounset" option* is not set (default in most cases))
$ # when "nounset" option is set (possibly using command "set -u") then bash will print such error:
$ # bash: array[${#array[@]} - 1]: unbound variable
$ unset "array[1]"    # always quote array elements when you unset them
$ echo ${#array[@]}
5
$ echo ${array[${#array[@]} - 1]}    # same as echo ${array[5 - 1]}
55555
```

That was obviously not the last element. To get the last element:

```
$ echo ${array[@]: -1}    # note the space before the minus sign
999999999
```

Note that in the upcoming Bash 4.2, you can do `echo ${array[-1]}` to get the last element. In versions prior to 4.2, you get a bad subscript error for negative subscripts.

To get the index of the last element:

```
$ idx=(${!array[@]})
$ echo ${idx[@]: -1}
9
```

Then you can do:

```
$ last=${idx[@]: -1}
$ echo ${array[last]}
999999999
```

To iterate over a sparse array:

```
for idx in ${!array[@]}
do
    something_with ${array[idx]}
done
```

---

* I recommend avoiding [`nounset`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/112)

Comment: It's not that simple… Set `LC_ALL=C` to count bytes rather than strings, and there's the memory used by the variable name (and the keys, for arrays), plus some extra for exported variables, plus some overhead.

Comment: woo hoo! `$(( ${#variable_name} + 1 ))` was exactly the pattern I was searching for! :) #different_context  #random

Answer (score 2):

```
${#VAR}
```

tells you the length of the string `VAR`

Comment: And for arrays you can expand them with `${ary[*]}` assign that to a temp variable and use the above to get the total of the values. Plus use `${!ary[*]}` to get a list of the keys. This is becoming complicated, isn't it?

Comment: you should set IFS="" to ensure that you dont introduce extra characters.  its a PITA, i know

Comment: True, but it's a far cry from memory used (in particular, less than half if the variable is exported, and potentially less in a multibyte locale since you're counting characters and not bytes).

Comment: ${#VAR} on an array gives the length of the first element (see Dennis Williamson's answer)

Answer (score 2):

For a scalar variable, `${#VAR}` gives you the length in characters. In a unibyte locale, this is the length in bytes. The size in bytes is the length of the name in bytes, plus the length of the value in bytes, plus a constant overhead.

```
LC_ALL=C
name=VAR
size=$(($#name + $#VAR)) # plus a small overhead
```

If the variable is exported, the size is roughly double.

```
LC_ALL=C
name=VAR
size=$((($#name + $#VAR) * 2)) # plus a small overhead
```

For an array variable, you need to sum up the lengths (again, in bytes) of the elements, and add a constant overhead per element plus a constant overhead for the array.

```
LC_ALL=C
name=VAR
size=$(($#name)) # plus a small overhead
for key in "${!VAR[@]}"; do
  size=$((size + ${#key} + ${#VAR[$key]})) # plus a small overhead
done
```

Here's a minimally tested function that computes the approximate size occupied by a variable. Arrays and exports are taken into account, but not special read-only variables such as `$RANDOM`. The sizes have been observed on bash 4.2, different versions may have different overheads. You may need to adjust the constants depending on your system types and `malloc` implementation.

```
_sizeof_pointer=4
_sizeof_int=4
_malloc_granularity=16
_malloc_overhead=16
## Usage: compute_size VAR
## Print the amount of memory (in bytes) used by VAR.
## The extra bytes used by the memory allocator are not taken into account.
add_size () {
  local IFS="+" this extra
  set $(($1 + _malloc_overhead))
  _size=$((_size + $1))
  set $(($1 % _malloc_granularity))
  [[ $1 -eq 0 ]] || _size=$((_size + _malloc_granularity - $1))
}
compute_size () {
  local LC_ALL=C _size=0 _key
  if eval "[ -z \${$1+1} ]"; then echo 0; return; fi
  add_size $((_sizeof_pointer*5 + _sizeof_int*2)) # constant overhead
  add_size ${#1} # the name
  case $(declare -p $1) in
    declare\ -x*)
      eval "add_size \${#$1}" # the value
      eval "add_size \$((\${#1} + \${#$1} + 2))" # the export string
      ;;
    declare\ -a*)
      eval 'for _key in "${!'$1'[@]}"; do
              add_size $_key
              add_size ${#'$1'[$_key]}
              add_size $((_sizeof_pointer*4))
            done'
      add_size $((_sizeof_pointer*2 + _sizeof_int*2))
      add_size $((_sizeof_pointer*4))
      ;;
    *)
      eval "add_size \${#$1}" # the value
      ;;
  esac
  echo $_size
}
```